# Configure default properties in Gradle precompiled plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to pass properties from precompiled script plugin to the project itself. I have precompiled script plugin inside of `buildSrc` directory.

1 In `buildSrc/gradle.properties` I have defined `defaultSpringBootVersion` property that holds value of `2.6.3`. This property is used in `buildSrc/build.gradle` to specify the `org.springframework.boot` plugin version.

2 At the same time I would like that the plugin itself located in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com.rivancic.convention-gradle-plugin.gradle` applies it to project properties:

```
project.ext{
  springBootVersion = defaultSpringBootVersion
}
```

3 If I try then in root project to access springBootVersion that I expect it will be available through the plugin, I get following error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.rivancic.convention-gradle-plugin']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.rivancic.convention-gradle-plugin'.
   > groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'defaultSpringBootVersion' for object of type org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.
```

Link to the example project: https://github.com/rivancic/gradle-plugin-properties

Representation: [image]

How to properly inject properties from `buildSrc/gradle.properties` into Precompiled Script Plugin, in this case `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com.rivancic.convention-gradle-plugin.gradle`